# Проблема передачи кириллицы VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, curl, кириллица

Запрашиваю выборку групп по запросу:

```
   $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.search?q=".$query."&count=".$count."&version=5.53&access_token=".$token."&offset=".$offset;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $gett = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

И столкнулся с проблемой: если передаю символы латиницы в параметре `q`, то VK API возвращает ответ нормально. Стоит же указать кириллицу — и API игнорирует, отсылая пустой ответ.

Думал, сначала, что дело в кодировке. Посмотрел, в какой кодировке возвращает ответ VK API — UTF-8, и пробовал указать в хедерах `Accept-Charset`, однако всё равно — ноль эмоций. Латиницу — кушает. Кириллицу — игнорирует.

При имитации запроса через браузер всё нормально, без всяких проблем.

`curl_error()` ничего не отдаёт.

Собственно, в чём может быть ещё проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте строку запроса так сформировать `$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.search?".http_build_query(array('q' => $query, 'count' => $count, 'version' => 5.53, 'access_token' => $token, 'offset' => $offset));`

Comment: Теперь как то странно. То пропускает все, то опять игнорит.

Comment: Может ограничения на количество запросов срабатывает, а не на содержимое переменной? И поставьте пару `'q' => $query` последней в массиве переменных на всякий пожарный.

Comment: @Visman, но ведь на запросы с латиницей сразу же реагирует, вот в чем дело.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перевести в URL
urlencode($query)

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает. Пробовал и с iconv() баловаться. Ноль эмоций

Comment: @ВиталийRS, а зачем с iconv(), если нужен UTF-8? У вас скрипт в другой кодировке работает?

Comment: @Visman, отчаяние привело к подобным тщетным попыткам, из разряда "а вдруг заработает"?
Самое интересное, что данный код, к примеру, стабильно запускается с рабочего сервера, и с лончера php из консоли. А вот в связке с бэкендом - глушь. Идёт в отказ.